# Python-like multiprocessing in C++

Tags: python, c++, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I am new to C++, and I am coming from a long background of Python.

I am searching for a way to run a function in parallel in C++. I read a lot about `std::async`, but it is still not very clear for me.

1. The following code does some really interesting thing

   ```
   #include <future>
   #include <iostream>

   void called_from_async() {
     std::cout << "Async call" << std::endl;
   }

   int main() {
     //called_from_async launched in a separate thread if possible
     std::future<void> result( std::async(called_from_async));

     std::cout << "Message from main." << std::endl;

     //ensure that called_from_async is launched synchronously
     //if it wasn't already launched
     result.get();

     return 0;
   }
   ```

   If I run it several times sometimes the output is what I expected:

   ```
   Message from main.
   Async call
   ```

   But sometimes I get something like this:

   ```
   MAessysnacg ec aflrlom main.
   ```

   Why isnt the `cout` happens first? I clearly call the `.get()` method AFTER the `cout`.
2. About the parallel runs. In case I have a code like this:

   ```
   #include <future>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   int twice(int m) {
     return 2 * m;
   }

   int main() {
     std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;

     for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
       futures.push_back (std::async(twice, i));
     }

     //retrive and print the value stored in the future
     for(auto &e : futures) {
       std::cout << e.get() << std::endl;
     }

     return 0;
   }
   ```

   All the 10 calls to `twice` function will run on separate cores simultaneously?

   In case not, is there a similar thing in C++ like the Python *multiprocess* lib?

   Mainly what I am searching for:

   I write a function, and call it with n number of inputs with ?multiprocessing? and it will run the function 1 times on n nodes at the same time.

Comment: Since `std::cout` is internally synchronised, your result should **never** occur. Is this actually the exact result you’re seeing? If so, that’s a compiler bug. — Another comment, please don’t add line numbers to the code you’re posting, it makes it harder for other people to copy&paste it to try the code out.

Comment: As for **1**: You want to run things in parallell, and then you're surprised when they run in parallell?

Comment: @Biffen In the parallel proicess i am not surprise, but as you see the first `cout` is NOT in parallel, and the parallel process is only called ONCE and AFTER the `cout`. That is what is confusing

Comment: Are you maybe mixing `cerr`and `cout`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer What does it have to do with `cerr`?

Comment: @GáborErdős You misunderstand how asynchronous futures operate. They are not executed when `.get` is called — `get` merely *ensures* that execution has completed, but they may well start executing beforehand. Otherwise, why would you expect a different behaviour for your second code? After all, `get` is called sequentially on all your futures.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, that explains the first part. So basically they are done whenever they are done, and by `.get()` i am just ensuring that they are done by that time?

Comment: @GáborErdős Depending on the execution policy … but in general (and in particular in the case of `std::async`), yes. However, this still doesn’t explain your garbled output, see my first comment.

Comment: @GáborErdős Mixing `cerr` and `cout` should be the only way this mixed up text can happen. Or when you are using a different output, but in this case your example would be wrong.

Comment: Do you need multiprocessing, or will multi-threading do? e.g. There's also p_threads for c++.  Coming from python where the GIL destroys the notion of multithreading, multiprocessing is essential. But in C and C++ you can do either.

Comment: @Pod C++ has a thread library in the standard library (header `<thread>`). pthreads is not standard C++, so there are portability issues to consider. And it is C.

Comment: @juanchopanza Good point. I don't use C++ any more so don't recall what was in C++11 (`<thread>`), so p_threads is probably a terrible example. I was mainly after figuring out if the OP actually wanted "multiprocessing" as they asked, e.g. via fork, or if threads are fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) `result.get();` does not start the thread. It only **waits** for the result. The parallel thread is launched with `std::async(called_from_async)` call (or whenever the compiler decides).

However `std::cout` is guaranteed to be internally thread safe. So the result you are showing us **should not** ever happen. There's a race condition, but you can't mix both outputs like that. If it really happens (which I doubt) then you might be dealing with a compiler bug.

2) Your calls will run parallely. On how many cores it depends on OS and other processes running on your machine. But there's a good chance that all will be used (assuming that you have control over whole ecosystem and no other cpu-intensive processes are running in the background).

There is no multiprocessing-like lib for C++ (at least not in the std). If you wish to run subprocesses then there are several options, e.g. forking or `popen` syscalls.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. One more question: Can i somehow specify the number of cores I wish to use, or C++ will use all of the available?

Comment: @GáborErdős That totally depends on the OS you are using. Some might give you ability to pick cores manually. AFAIK it is possible on both posix and windows, but I wouldn't go down that road - it's messy and requires a lot knowledge about the kernel. Also note that multiprocessing deals with the same issue.

Comment: I am only asking because i am planning to use scripts on a HPC. If it uses all of the available cores is okey for me, was just curious. In python multiprocessing i can define a `Pool(4)` and it will run on 4 cores.

Comment: @GáborErdős No. It will run 4 processes which are not guaranteed to run on 4 cores. As I said: that depends on OS. But still you should not worry about it, it's a subtlety. OS should do its job properly. :)

Comment: Ohh yes you are right. Is there a way to specify the number of processors then?

Comment: @GáborErdős Sure. In the context of threads you just call `std::async(called_from_async)` as many times as you wish (your second snippet does exactly that). By default it will spawn a new thread each time. Unlike Python C++ is not limited by GIL so they will run in parallel.

Comment: Use the `int n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();` to detect and decide parallelism in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the above solutions by the calculation of a matrix with the help of async call. This saved me a lot of time when calculating correlation matrices of climate data. (Just in case someone else needs this to calculate something)

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int twice(int m) {
    return 2 * m;
}

void compute_row(int* row) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++) row[i] = twice(i);
}

void compute(int** matrix) {
    std::vector<std::future<void> > futures;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) futures.push_back(std::async(compute_row, matrix[i]));

    // wait for it
    for (auto& e : futures) e.get();
}

int main() {
    int** results = new int*[10];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++) results[i] = new int[10];
    compute(results);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 10; j++) std::cout << results[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `g++ std=c++11 -o doit doit.cpp`